# plot3d hyperelliptic singular curve

Tags: graphing-functions, riemann-surfaces, sagemath

I am trying to draw a singular hyperelliptic curve of genus two in Sage. My goal is to obtain something that looks like (including the oriented one-cycles):
[image]

I think that the equation of such a pinched Riemann surface is given by $y^2=x^2(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$ for pairwise distinct complex numbers $a,b,c,d$.

here is the code I use, it doesn't give me a pinched Riemann surface

```
x, y, z=var('x,y,z')
f=y**2-x**2*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)*(x-4)
f
implicit_plot3d(f,(x,-pi,pi),(y,-pi,pi),(z,-1,1),color="automatic",thickness=3, aspect_ratio=(1,1,1))
```

It gives something different:

[image]

I suspect that the problem is that my variables $x,y$ are real and not complex. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't speak Sage, but in addition to the point you raise (real vs. complex variables), the plot range needs to encompass all the roots of the right-hand side in order to include the resulting topological handles. (It appears $x$ and $y$ go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, while the roots are $0$, ..., $4$.)

Comment: Thank you, I used even range from -10 to +10 and I get the same shape. Is it possible to do it in Tikz for instance?

Comment: The short answers: I expect a mathematically-accurate plot will be (i) vexing to produce with plotting software and (ii) practically impossible to create manually, and (iii) will not show the topology as clearly as the line drawing in the post. Is there a reason not to use the line drawing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I think now I am convinced that it is better to do line drawing (If you mean by that the first plot I put in my question). I just wandered if I could give it more life, colours, shading etc. but if it is complicated, that's fine with line drawing